# vlc media player plugin in Internet explorer not showing video in fiddler

Tags: apache-flex, fiddler, vlc

I am currently trying to debug a flex application that uses a vlc media player plugin to watch mpeg-2 videos.

I have run up Fiddler and I can see lots of calls from the flex application for resources it uses but when I play a video in the player, I do not see any requests for the video in Fiddler.

Any ideas how to get Fiddler to show the http traffic when a video is played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler will show any HTTP/HTTPS traffic that is sent through it. For traffic not seen in Fiddler, there are two possibilities:

1> The traffic is non-HTTP/HTTPS (e.g. straight TCP/IP).
2> The traffic is HTTP/HTTPS but is not configured to go through the proxy.

If the traffic is non-HTTP/HTTPS, there's nothing you can do to get it to appear in Fiddler.

If the traffic is HTTP/HTTPS but isn't using the system's default proxy, you may be able to configure it to do so. For instance, I don't know if the VLC plugin respects the settings from the VLC client, but try clicking Tools > Preferences > Input & Codecs and put `127.0.0.1:8888` the box for the proxy URL.

Comment: Thank you Eric. It looks like the VLC media plugin does not respect the settings from the VLC client. I will need to see how I can set that which should then help me resolve other issues. Thanks once again.